# Chart.js pie chart not showing

Tags: javascript, charts, chart.js

```js
var upDataC = [];
for (var i = 1; i < upData.length; i++) {
  upDataC[i - 1] = upData[i];
  var datasetsx = [];
  var datas;

  for (var j = 0; j < lData.length; j++) {
    datas = 0;
    var x = Math.floor((Math.random() * 220) + 1);
    var y = Math.floor((Math.random() * 220) + 1);
    var z = Math.floor((Math.random() * 220) + 1);
    var temp = allData[j];
    for (var w = 0; w < temp.length; w++) {
      var temp2 = temp[w];
      datas = parseInt(parseInt(datas) + parseInt(temp2));
    }

    datasetsx[j] = {
      label: lData[j],
      color: 'rgba(' + z + ',' + y + ',' + x + ',1)',
      highlight: 'rgba(' + z + ',' + y + ',' + x + ',1)',
      value: datas,
    }
  }

  var data = {
    labels: upDataC,
    datasets: datasetsx,
  };
  var ctx = $("#myChart").get(0).getContext("2d");
  var newGraph = new Chart(ctx).Pie(data);


}


Chart.defaults.global = {
  animation: true,
  animationSteps: 60,

}
Chart.defaults.global.responsive = true;
var options = "";
var selected = false;
if (selected === false) {} else {
  legend(document.getElementById("data"), data);
}
};
```

```html
<script src="https://github.com/nnnick/Chart.js/blob/master/Chart.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="charts">
  <canvas id="myChart"></canvas>
  <div id="data"></div>
</div>
```

```
var datasetsx = [];
            var datas;

            for (var j =0; j < lData.length; j++) {
            datas = 0;
            var x = Math.floor((Math.random()*220)+1);
            var y = Math.floor((Math.random()*220)+1);
            var z = Math.floor((Math.random()*220)+1);
                var temp = allData[j];
                for (var w = 0 ; w<temp.length; w++){
                var temp2 = temp[w];
                datas = parseInt(parseInt(datas) + parseInt(temp2));
                }

                datasetsx[j] = 
                                   {
                                       label : lData[j],
                                       color: 'rgba('+ z + ',' + y + ',' + x + ',1)' ,
                                       highlight :'rgba('+ z + ',' + y + ',' + x + ',1)' ,
                                       value : datas,
                                   }
                    }

            var data = {
                labels: upDataC,
                datasets: datasetsx,
            };
            var ctx = document.getElementById("myChart").getContext("2d");
            var newGraph = new Chart(ctx).Pie(data);


            }
```

I can only post this to help you understand better, but I can't share the whole thing as it belong to a company.

It is supposed to generate a Pie chart. The chart is apparently on the screen even though it's blank. var data isn't empty though, just FYI. Also, the legend I generate shows the data that should be inserted, and it's right there, so the info the chart uses to generate itself is there

Comment: There a syntax error, I can't find isn't any `{` for your last `}`

Comment: can you create jsfiddle?

Comment: your code is total mess, it will be really helpful to find bug if you can create http://jsfiddle.net with some dummy data.

Comment: Unfortunately the piece of code before is pretty complex to rewrite in order for this to work. I cannot provide any more data. It seems like this will stay unresolved, thanks anyway :(

Comment: Make sure you get a proper data object for pie chart and check for some syntax error if any. I hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

```
var data = datasetsx;
```

This actually solved the issue.
the variable "data" should not have been declared like I did before, it has its own style which differs from bar and line ones!

Thankyou for your help!